# Что такое php echo?

Tags: php, клиент-сервер, rest

Существующее определение: "вывод текста". Куда echo выводит текст? И каким образом браузер этот текст получает?

В интересующем меня случае: если браузер отправляет http get-запрос серверу, то через echo в итоге от сервера клиенту посылается так же get ответ?

Comment: echo - вывод текста в браузер. От сервера клиенту отправляется http-ответ, не может быть post/get/put/delete ответа. По этому поводу советую почитать про http протокол и его работу

Comment: не в браузер а в стандартный вывод. это может быть и консоль и файл и т.п.

Comment: пока неправильные ответы.

Comment: Понятия "get ответ" не существует. Да, PHP пишет в буфер вывода (если установлен перехват вывода), при опустошении буфера это попадает в следующий пункт назначения - либо тело HTTP-ответа (который отправится после завершения работы скрипта), если PHP обрабатывает HTTP-запрос, либо в stdout, если PHP работает в консольном режиме. Точной спецификации по этому вопросу нет, так что есть вероятность существования какого-то дополнительного жонглирования точкой вывода.

Comment: Вот странность, если мы отправляем get-запрос на сервер, где выполняется php и выводится текст через echo. После чего браузер как-то получает ответ. Но ведь get-запросы не имеют тела? Тогда каким образом мы получаем текст в ответе?
Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: В том, что браузеру возвращается обычный ответ, у которого вполне себе есть тело, get-запрос - это только то, что отправляет сам браузер.

Comment: что значит обычный ответ? Какого типа этот ответ? По какому протоколу он идет? Я прочитал про http, явного ответа не нашел.

Comment: В HTTP нет понятия "тип ответа". На все запросы ответ имеет одинаковую структуру и состоит из статусной строки, заголовков, разделителя и непосредственно тела ответа. Не существует никаких правил или рекомендаций, запрещающих отправку тела ответа на GET-запрос. Ответ, конечно, идет по тому же HTTP-протоколу, что и запрос.

Comment: благодаря вам я понял, что ответы идут в рамках одного коннекта, будь то get или post и своей спецификации у них нет. Спасибо.

Comment: etki, напишите чуть подробнее про устройство буфер вывода и вот этот комментарий про ответ в http в отдельном посте. Отмечу как решение.

Comment: @etki некоторые коды ответов HTTP запрещают отправлять тело, к примеру [The 304 response MUST NOT contain a message-body](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5)

Comment: @andreymal и все равно GET-запрос не является условием, которое запрещает отправлять тело

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Браузер отправляет запрос с указанием

   1. IP адреса сервера (вычисляется по имени домена при помощи DNS сервера)
   2. Номера порта (по умолчанию 80 для http и 443 для https)
   3. Адреса страницы на этом сервере
2. Веб-сервер, который сидит на указанном IP адресе и который слушает указанный порт получает TCP-пакет, достает из него адрес страницы и смотрит, кто этот адрес будет обрабатывать (алгоритм поиска обработчика - вопрос отдельный)
3. Создает настройки окружения и запускает обработчик
4. Если был вызван PHP обработчик, то он создает буфер вывода и выполняет нужный скрипт
5. Скрипт, при помощи команд `echo`, `header`, `setcookie` заполняет этот буфер
6. PHP обработчик после окончания работы скрипта, или по мере заполнения буфера, отдает этот буфер запустившему веб-серверу.
7. Веб-сервер может дополнительно обработать этот буфер (например, сжать его) и отправляет по TCP запросившему клиенту
8. Браузер получает TCP пакет, достает и обрабатывает содержимое